# "Conveniently situated close" vs "conveniently close situated"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, grammaticality-in-context, modifiers, adjective-order

> The hotel is conveniently ***situated*** ***close*** to the beach.

Does ***situated*** describe ***close*** in this sentence?

And, could we exchange their places with one another, in this way: conveniently ***close*** ***situated***?

Comment: You could say **situated conveniently close to the beach** if you wanted to modify **close**.  *The dorm room is situated annoyingly close to the dumpster.*

Comment: Does “conveniently” before “situated” mean “easily”? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: **conveniently situated** means "in a convenient location". There is some convenience to be had from the location.

Answer (score 2):

Rather, we say *close to the beach* completes *situated*.

*Close to* is indivisible; it functions as a single unit, whose part of speech is preposition ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close_to#Preposition)).

To take a very basic view of the syntax — pardon the lack of newer grammatical concepts:

> *adjective phrase*
>   
> Situated            [at location]
>   
>                                   ↓
>   
>                     *preposition phrase*
>   
>                  close to          [location]
>   
>                                              ↓
>   
>                                      *noun phrase*
>   
>                                        the beach

As you can see, there's no way to move *situated* between *close* and *to* in this structure without the thing falling apart.

To get a sense of how the phrase works:

1. "The beach" answers the question "Close to what?"
2. "Close to the beach" answers the question "Where is it situated?"